# A .iml file for each time I duplicated my android project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an android project, let's call it `myProject`. I made a couple copies of it using copy paste so that I could significantly change one without messing up the original. For example I had:

```
myProject
myProject_copy1
myProject_copy2
```

I was recently looking at the files in my android project and noticed that there is a seperate .iml file (not really sure what an iml file is anyways) for each copy I made. So my `myProject` project has a:

```
myProject.iml
myProject_copy1.iml
myProject_copy2.iml
```

What are these and can I delete any?

Comment: duplicate question - see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737082/what-are-iml-files-in-android-studio

Comment: @Jim I've read this but it doesn't seem to apply to my question of having an iml file for each time I duplicated my project and whether I can remove them.

Comment: It states that IML files store information about each module - and each of your projects is a module. The "copies" of your project have different locations, etc. You can remove them, but they will be recreated. Why would you want to remove them?