# What does IntelliJ IDEA .iml do?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have seen this file, and I know it can record some config.
But what the hell does this file config, that is to say, what kind of file does it config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are iml files in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737082/what-are-iml-files-in-android-studio)

Comment: Nothing at all. Ignore it, but don't delete it or you'll get in trouble ;)